# Custom 301 redirect rule .gif.html to .jpg.html

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to redirect pages like this:

www.my-some-site.com/folder/subfolder/image-name.gif.html

to:

www.my-some-site.com/folder/subfolder/image-name.jpg.html

just to rewrite "**.gif.html**" to "**.jpg.html**"

---

"/folder/" in my case is just an example, actual category and subcategory names are different. I need that rewrite rule for pages in all categories, for urls which ends with ".gif.html". Practically any page URL that have ".gif.html" to be 301 redirected to that same page but to have ".jpg.html".

Note: This is URL of html page/post, not URL of image.

www.my-some-site.com/folder/subfolder/image-name.gif.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectMatch` rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^.]+)\.gif\.html$ /$1.jpg.html
```

Comment: "/folder/" in my case is just example, actual category names are different. I need that rewrite rule for pages in all categories, for urls which ends with ".gif.html". Practically any page URL that have ".gif.html" to be 301 redirected to that same page but to have ".jpg.html".

Comment: Still not working, with that I have 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Could you please look at it again? By the way tanks for quick previous update.

Comment: I modified and it should work. If you get 500 then can you check apache error.log and tell me what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Better asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), I voted to migrate.

I'll also add that serving things ending in ".gif.html" or ".jpg.html" looks like a bad idea.  What is it?  A gif?  A jpg?  An HTML file?  You should make sure the [MIME type being served](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME_headers) is correct in the response header, in any case.

I've done some of this in Apache configs lately, not `.htaccess` files.  I'm not really familiar with the differences in syntax/semantics, but if in the Apache config you say:

```
    RewriteEngine on
```

Then you can write:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\.gif\.html$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif\.html$ $1\.jpg\.html [R=301]
```

@anubhava has provided an alternative and may well know more than I do, about something I wish I didn't have to know about.  :-)

Comment: It is HTML (post/page) URL, not of image.

Comment: @user1038179 There was an extra backslash in the first line for some reason, typo I guess.  You might try it without that extra backslash in `\html` on the RewriteCond *(or the update from @anubhava)*